# align cell in itextpdf java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using itextpdf to create my pdf with tables. While creating table i need to align some column to right, but its now working properly , can you guys help me.

I tried googling too, but didt work out for me. im using itextpdf 5.4 version.

```
 public void generateMonthlySubReport(String[][] StrArray,String dueMonth,int Amt){
    try {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(MON_SUB_FILE));         
        PdfPTable pt = new PdfPTable(StrArray[0].length); 
        pt.setTotalWidth(new float[]{ 55,120,360,140});
        pt.setLockedWidth(true);
        PdfPCell pcell = new PdfPCell();
        document.open();                        
        addKvLogo(document); 
        Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Monthly Subscription Report",catFont);
        p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        addEmptyLine(p1,2);
        document.add(p1);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Month : "+dueMonth);
        p2.add(new Chunk(glue));
        p2.add("Per Member : Rs."+Amt);        
        addEmptyLine(p2,2);
        document.add(p2);

        for(int i=0;i<StrArray.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<StrArray[i].length;j++){ 
                pcell = new PdfPCell();
                if(i==0){
                    pcell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }else{
                    pcell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
                }                    
                pcell.setUseAscender(true);
                pcell.setMinimumHeight(22);
                pcell.setPaddingLeft(10);                    
                pcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                pcell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                pcell.addElement(new Phrase(StrArray[i][j]));
                pt.addCell(pcell);
            }
        }            
        pt.setTotalWidth(PageSize.A4.getWidth()-(document.leftMargin()*2));
        pt.setLockedWidth(true);
        document.add(pt);
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        

}             `
```

Comment: Somebody voted to close the question, and also gave you a down-vote. However, this is a genuine question, hence my up-vote. I would recommend to read the documentation in the future, though, because what I wrote in my answer is documented in many places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing **text mode** with **composite mode**.

This is **text mode**:

```
pcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(StrArray[i][j]));
pcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

In this case, the alignment of the cell will be used for the alignment of the text.

This is **composite mode**:

```
pcell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph p = new Parapgraph(StrArray[i][j])
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
pcell.addElement(p);
```

In this case, the alignment of the cell is ignored, in favor of the alignment of the element.

**How to know the difference between text mode and composite mode?**

iText automatically switches from text mode to composite mode in a `PdfPCell` the moment you use the `addElement()` method. As soon as you do this, some properties defined at the cell level are ignored. This explains why the content you are adding isn't right-aligned.